# Errror: external entity error, getURl error

Tags: r, web-scraping

I found this wonderful code on GitHub (https://github.com/rpodcast/nhl_analysis/blob/master/web-scraping/hockey-reference-boxscore-scratch.R), as I am new to R and more familiar to matlab, my goal was just to use the code to get the data I want. I just copied the code from his github, i imported every possible package. 
After executing the code in RStudio, i get this problem:

> table.stats <- readHTMLTable(full.url, header=FALSE)
>   Error: failed to load external entity "http://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/199511210BOS.html"

I tried to solve the problem with other Q&A from here, but wasnt able to. I tried to rewrite it using the httr-package instead of the RCurl package, but this doesnt work.

I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The codes you're using are last updated 7 years ago. And websites frequently change their HTML design, so codes are not guaranteed to work.

Use the following codes instead.

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)

ua <- user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36")
url <- 'https://www.hockey-reference.com/boxscores/199511210BOS.html'
session <- html_session(url,ua)

session %>%
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    html_table()
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! 
I think the rest of the old code wont work either, so I will have to clean the data myself. I have one question: I can run the code, and see the output in the console, but i cannot identify the variable storing the data? is it html_table() which returns the data? I tried to save the date using data <- html_table() but I am getting an error.

Comment: There are six tables in the web page. So it is displayed as a list with length of six. Each element in the list is a table.